# How to use express-boom badRequest

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

I am new to node+express and trying to use express-boom module.I found below snippet on the express website but not sure how to invoke this? How to return reasons object from a controller?

```
import boom from "express-boom";
app.use(function (req, res) {
    // some validation check fail and returns an object : reasons
    res.boom.badRequest("Validation didn't succeed", reasons);
});
```

In mainController.js, I have tried using this but no success.

```
/*res.status(400).send({
                    message: 'Unrecognized Broker name'
});*/ //Want to replace this code and make it compatible with express-boom
res.send({"reasons":"Unrecognized broker name"}); // this returns 200
```

Comment: Please post the entire code for both index and controller file

Answer (score 2):

You first need to set up your app to use the `express-boom` middleware:

```
import boom from 'express-boom';

...

app.use(boom());
```

The above makes `boom` available as a property of `res` on all middleware and route handling functions in your app.

Then, in your controller, to send a 400 response with a message:

```
res.boom.badRequest('Unrecognized broker name')
```

This will send a response with a 400 status code and a body that includes

```
{ "message": "Unrecognized broker name" }
```